# can't use the GAC for EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, .net-assembly, gac

I'm using the GAC to share dll's.

Here, I have an application that use the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll 5.0.414.0. if I put it on the same folder than the .exe, all is OK, but when I want to remove it from this folder, it doesn't working, even if I installed it on the GAC...

I installed it on the GAC thanks to

```
D:\Applications\Services\App>GACUTIL.exe -i Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

When I remove this dll from this folder, the app isn't run correctly, why?

I tried the GAC woth others dll's and it's ok, and When I go to C:\WINDOWS\assembly, the dll looks like it's installed!

I already re-tryed to install it with the CLI that I shown you before.

**EDIT:**

Type:

```
Exception type:
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException, Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Message:

```
Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key ""
```

Stack:

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService]()
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer()
MyFramework.Logging.MyLogger.WriteVerbose(String applicationName, String title, String logText)
MyApp.Fleet_Service.GetInfo(Int32 accountid, String[] msisdns, DateTime from, DateTime to) in c:\Clients\Project\V1\Fleet_Service.cs:line 111
SyncInvokeGetInfo(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
```

Thanks to help me

Comment: What do you meant by *app isn't run correctly* ?

Comment: Exception when I try a method that use this DLL. If I Add this DLL on the app's folder, all works fine without exception!

Comment: Well, post the exception type, message, stacktrace etc

Comment: `ActivationException` is something which is specific to `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` which I honestly don't know. Am sure this is not due to loading the dll, If clr can't find dll it will throw `FileNotFoundException` and when it can find dll but different version or something it will throw `FileLoadException`. I suggest you to look at documentation why this exception happens.

Comment: @Sriam ok thanks but hum... When I put Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll in the app's folder, no problem. if I delete it, problem. This is the same assembly that is in the GAC, I installed yesterday... I double check this is the same version, and we don't have custom version of this dll!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the .NET version you are using, the GAC might not be in `C:\Windows\Assembly`.
For .NET 4, the GAC is located at `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\`.
In general, if you want to understand why a .NET application does not find an assembly, you should use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tool (fuslogvw.exe from a VS command prompt).

*EDIT*: after seeing your comment, it could be that it's not your application directly that is trying to load the assembly that fails, but maybe some other dll. Use the assembly binding log viewer tool to determine what is failing and why. Also, it would be better if you provided some more details on how your application is failing (error message, stack trace...)

Comment: Ok thanks,and how can I install the app in the propper GAC? I tried to put 5+ others DLL on the GAC with the same command and When I remove those dll, it works fine

Comment: @clement: to install the dll in the proper GAC, on a machine with VS installed, you must just use the proper version of gacutil.

Comment: thanks! When I run the Assembly Binding Lov Viewer I see no Application.. My app is a Windows Service...

Comment: I put 10+ Dll's in the GAC, and if I remove them all except the enterpriselibrarydata, it works fine! it is only when I remove this dll that the exception appears

Comment: Yes! I made, sign and put in GAP a sort of framework that I use for logging! This framework use Enterprise Library! I put Exception Details in first comment